# Warning before the checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
function alter_payment_gateways( $list ) {
    // Retrieve chosen shipping options from all possible packages
    $chosen_rates = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();

    if( in_array('betrs_shipping:2-1', $chosen_rates ) ) {
        $array_diff = array('WC_Gateway_COD');
        $list = array_diff( $list, $array_diff );
    }
    else if( in_array('betrs_shipping:2-2', $chosen_rates ) ) {
        $array_diff = array('WC_Gateway_COD');
        $list = array_diff( $list, $array_diff );
    }
    return $list;
}
add_action('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'alter_payment_gateways');
```

I get these two warnings for this code. The code is still working but i want to solved the warnings.

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: The warning seems pretty clear.  The `in_array` function expects `$chosen_rates` to be an array, but `$chosen_rates` is `null`.

Comment: Oh ok my fault. Thank you.